# Disable and enable all spring batch job through a internal rest api call by passing a boolean flag(enable or disable)

Tags: spring-batch

I have created a job status table where i have a boolean flag based on that i am returning the cron expreesion(active cron or hypen(-) cron) and my scheduler will work.
Boolean flag will be updated if you want to enable or disable all spring batch jobs.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronValueDevice}")
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronValueStorage}")
```

```
@Bean
public String getCronValueDevice() {
JobStatus jobStatus = jobStatusRepository.findByJobName(BatchJobConstants.DEVICE_JOB_NAME);
if (jobStatus != null && jobStatus.getIsActive()) {
    return jobStatus.getActiveCronExpression();
} else {
    return "-";
}
}
```

Is there anything in  builtin spring scheduler or anything in timer framework which will help this requirement to enable or disable all spring batch jobs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. What do you mean "disable/enable" all spring batch jobs? Please elaborate by adding more details about your setup and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your approach of trying to change the cron expression at runtime to enable/disable batch jobs is not the best option IMO. I would keep it simple and do the check inside the scheduled method. This way, the cron expression does not need to change, and the flag that controls if the job should be launched or not can be dynamically changed. I voted to re-open the question. I can add an answer if it is re-opened.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine please add an answer once its re-opened to control the flag

Comment: @Billal Begueradj  please help in re-opening the question to have a concrete solution of above spring batch problem